# Open Mozilla Firefox Browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

My Application would default start with Google Chrome. When User access one of the Menu Option , I would like to Open

That URL with Mozilla Firefox Browser. Not Google Chrome.

Can someone please help me on the same? Is this possible to Open explicit browser from JavaScript?

Thanks , Niraj Salot.

Comment: I certainly hope it's not possible to open an application from javascript, but sadly I've been wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser is opened is dependant on the users OS (if the browser is present, which browser is their primary etc etc), as such it's not something that can be done through a browser.

It would also be a massive security risk as if a browser *could* open an external application it would be open to exploits and abuses pretty much from the get go.

About the only permissiable way would be create a plug-in for Chrome which could request from the user if they would like to open the link in another browser, but then thats a alot of work for this.

You'd be better off checking what browser is being used (again since you have no control over which one the users are using) and politely ask that they open the link in firefox.